# Informix and spring batch jdbc page reader

Tags: spring-batch, informix

I'm new to spring batch.  Is there any specific implementation of `jdbcpagereader` for Informix since spring batch doesn't offer such class?

I want to multi-thread my job since I'm reading a big amount of data.  I heard that `oraclepagereader` is suitable, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: What was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that  jdbcpagingsueryprovider dosn t support  informix and generate queries that dont use its specific SKIP LIMIT grammar.

I m looking for a solution tu use a thread safe paging item reader for informix.

Thanks

Comment: After heavy debugging i found out that the sql generator bean provided by spring batch dosnt support informix so i created my own sqlpagingprovider and sqlpagingitemreader.

Comment: please can you share you `sqlpagingprovider` and `sqlpagingitemreader` ?